# How to retrieve automatically uploaded form data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to post data automatically with javascript and retrieve it in a PHP file, but the PHP file does not retrieve the data.

I created an automatic form which receives its input from another form and automatically sends it to another PHP file. But the next file pics.php does not receive the data. I only posted the relevant part of the code. First the HTML/javascript code.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{   document.getElementById("auto").click(); 
    document.auto.submit();    
}
</script>

<body onload="submit()">
<form name="auto" id="auto" action="pics.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name= "prodnm" value="<?php echo 
 $prodnm; ?>" /><br/>
<input type="hidden" name= "eigid" value="<?php echo $eigid; 
 ?>" /><br/>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

And this is part of the PHP code in file pics.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
$prodnm = $_POST['prodnm'];
$eigid = $_POST['eigid'];
echo $prodnm;
echo $eigid;                    
?>
```

Help is very much appreciated. I've been at it for two days straight.

Comment: Relative URLs in the JS action field look within the website itself, is pics.php in the same directory then?

Comment: `<?php echo $prodnm; ?>` will throw warnings for undefined variable. PHP 7+ use `<?= $prodnm ?? ''; ?>` See [null closure](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types).

Comment: So what debugging have you done?  If you've been at it for two days, I'd like to think you could give us more information that just saying it doesn't work.

Comment: As alluded to by @PatrickQ already, what doesn't work? What does `connect.php` have inside it that could be causing issues and is error reporting enabled?

Comment: If you use Chrome learn how to use the debug console, it is very useful : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

Comment: why use this approach in the first place? It seems there are better approaches that this

Comment: And how exactly are the PHP variables being populated in your form?  Those are hidden fields, so they're not going to be filled in by a user, so how are they getting values to be posted?  You say that you've included relevant code, but I'm afraid you've left out some crucial information.

Comment: `"I created an automatic form which receives its input from another form"` - please explain what an `"automatic form"` is

Comment: @john-sno Do you care to answer any of these questions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is how it works.
First page product.php is a form that submits data to another form auto.php.
auto.php uses the data to create two dynamic files agenda_variablenm.php and webpage_variablenm.php and automatically uploads two parameters  into a file pics.php.
pics.php uses the parameters along with 4 input files to upload pictures into the webpage_variablenm.php.
Problem
I can automatically upload data from upload.php into pics.php as long as it is not variable data. But I need to load variable data which I retrieve from the products.php and there's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Am afraid the approach you are using is not advisable.

The form seems not to be getting the values you said are from another form(who does that anyway?).

Why not use a single form that has a submit button.

Define default values to you input fields(both visible and hidden, as you wish.)

Then use the JavaScript code to auto submit the default values on page load.

## Remember, there are always better and less complicated ways to write codes for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code above I cannot see why you could not send the data via an ajax request rather than trying to populate a form and then trigger the submit method somehow... Perhaps the following might be of interest in that regard.

```
/* replace the inline submit handler with a remote listener */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

    /* a very basic ajax function to send a POST request */
    const ajax=function( url, params, callback ){
        let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload=function(){
            if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback( this.response )
        };
        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
        xhr.send( params );
    };

    /* for convenience, declare PHP variables as Javascript variables */
    <?php
        printf("
            let prodnm='%s';
            let eigid='%s';\n",
            $prodnm,
            $eigid
        );
    ?>

    /* Make the POST request to pics.php */
    ajax( 'pics.php', 'prodnm='+prodnm+'&eigid='+eigid, r=>{
        alert("Do something with result?\n\nResponse: "+r+"\n\nReload? Modify DOM?")
    });
});
```

As the data exists in PHP at the point you are trying to POST the form and because there is no intended human interaction then you could use curl ( or similar ) and negate the need for this page.

Comment: Thanks RamRaider. I will have a look at the code you sent. I dont know Ajax but I will try to make sense of it.

Comment: Thanks everybody for pitching in. It started to work all of the sudden. Exactly how it was written. The problem was with the mysql database.